# PHP - Document Database - Unable to open in Safari on iOS

Tags: php, ios, safari, mime-types, content-type

I have database of files that users can search/download via an online PHP driven website. I contains PDF, .doc, .docx files etc. So far everything is working fine on the desktop on Mac/Windows.

We are now testing the site on iOS 9 with mobile Safari and we're getting a strange error when we click the link to download one of the .docx files:

```
Unable to Read Document
An error occurred while reading the document
```

If I save the document as a .doc file and update the database it then downloads successfully. In the PHP page I'm setting the content-header based on the file extension as follows:

```
if($url == "jpg"){ 
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
} else if($url == "gif"){ 
 header('Content-type: image/gif'); 
} else if($url == "doc"){ 
 header('Content-type: application/msword');
} else if($url == "dot"){ 
 header('Content-type: application/msword');
} else if($url == "docx"){ 
 header('Content-type: application/msword');
} else if($url == "xls"){ 
 header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
} else if($url == "xlsx"){ 
 header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
} else if($url == "png"){ 
 header('Content-type: image/png');
} else if($url == "pdf"){ 
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
} else if($url == "mp3"){ 
 header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
// set default
} else{ 
 header('Content-type: application/force-download');
```

}

Is there a different content-type header I should be setting or some other change I can make to get mobile Safari to recognise it's a .docx file and open it like it normally would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had the wrong header for a .docx file. It should be set to:

```
} else if($url == "docx"){ 
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
```